# Regular expression arithmetics

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

What are the rules of regular expression arithmetics ?

For example: Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$

$1. 1+01=(\epsilon+0)1$.

$2. (\epsilon+00)^*=(00)^*$

Comment: What exactly is you question?

Comment: @martini - "What are the rules of regular expression arithmetics ?" in $\mathbb{R}$ for exmaple you have $ab+ac=a(b+c)$ and in the examples I gave there are cirtin rules for regular expression arithmetics as well...I ask about what those rules are (although I do understand that in $\mathbb{R}$ this was an axiom and in our case it can be proven)

Comment: Perhaps look into [Kleene algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra).

Comment: What regular expression syntax are you using? In the RE syntaxes I know `+` is either an ordinary character, or means "one or more times the regular expression preceding it" (i.e. like `*`, but excluding the empty string). Here, it seems to mean something different (maybe "or")?

Comment: @celtschk: Belgi is clearly using it for OR; I’m more familiar with both $\mid$ and $\lor$ in this context, but I’ve also seen $+$ used.

Comment: See [Kleene algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head you have at least the following:

1. $\epsilon\alpha=\alpha=\alpha\epsilon$.
2. $\alpha+\beta=\beta+\alpha$.
3. $\alpha+\alpha=\alpha$.
4. $\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma=\alpha(\beta+\gamma)$ and $\beta\alpha+\gamma\alpha=(\beta+\gamma)\alpha$.
5. $(\epsilon+\alpha)^*=\epsilon+\alpha^*=\alpha^*$.
6. $\epsilon^*=\epsilon$.

If your formalization includes $\varnothing$ (no string) distinct from $\epsilon$ (empty string), you have $\varnothing+\alpha=\alpha$.